# how to install third party tool in anaconda python distribution

Tags: 14.04, python, anaconda

I installed anaconda python distribution at location:

```
/home/user/softwares/anaconda/
```

Now I want to install a third party tool essentia. It can't be installed using `pip`. So I have to download and build the files. The instructions are given in [this link](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/installing.html).

But the installation is not reflected in anaconda distribution. When I import the package in anaconda it says no module found. But when I run default python distribution from `/usr/bin/python2.7`  I am able to import the package. Clearly it is installed in default python but not in anaconda distribution. How do I install it in anaconda python distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add it to anaconda, but you can add the directory where the source files are to the $PYTHONPATH environment variable, this way any python you're using will be able to 'see' what's in there.

So if you have it on `~/my_python_packages/essentia` you would have to do:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:~/my_python_packages"
```